# How to retrieve data from indexedDB in service worker?

Tags: javascript, caching, indexeddb, service-worker, fetch-api

I've stored json data in the indexedDB and want to retrieve it when the application requests for it in the service worker, but i'm getting an error saying error fetching the script for service worker. 
My Service worker code is like this :

```
importScripts('idb.js');
const cache_v = 'a2',
cache_all = [
'shell_'+cache_v,
'data_'+cache_v
],

statics = [
'index.html',
'app.js',
'idb.js'
];


this.addEventListener('install',e=>{
  console.log("Installing Service Worker");
  console.log("Storing Static Data");
  e.waitUntil(
    caches.open(cache_all[0])
    .then(cac=>cac.addAll(statics))
    .catch(er=>console.error(er))
  )
  console.log("Installation Complete");
});

this.addEventListener('activate',e=>{
  console.log("Service worker activated, now clearing obsolete data");
})

this.addEventListener('fetch',e=>{
    if(e.request.url === 'https://api.github.com/users/abt10/repos'){
       console.log("IndexDB Reqrd");
       let db = idb.open('Projects_info')
       .then(d=>{
        let ob = d.transaction('proj_dat');
        let data = ob.objectStore('proj_dat');
        let fd = data.getAll()
        .then(dt=>{
            return dt;
        })
    })
}
else{
    e.respondWith(caches.match(e.request)
    .then((res)=>{
        return res || fetch(e.request).then(res=>{if(res.status === 404)  
        return new Response("Not Found");});
    })
    )
}
console.log('fetched');
})
```

I can't find what's the error.

Comment: Need to look at whatever idb.js is doing. Hard to answer a question about indexedDB when you post code that uses a library that wraps indexedDB and don't include the relevant part of the library or clarify where to examine the library.

Comment: idb library by Jake Archibald. It's on GitHub.

Comment: https://github.com/jakearchibald/idb

Comment: Can you post the exact error message you're seeing?

Comment: "An unknown error occured while fetching the script.              service_worker.js:1"

Answer (score 0):

my guess is you need to properly path your idb.js reference from your web site's root. example:

```
importScripts('/js/idb.js');
```

Comment: It's in the same directory path as the service worker

Comment: check your network waterfall to see if there are any 404s on the URLs you are caching. Make sure you can isolate what file is not being found. I think your issue is not with IDB, but with a file not being found.

Comment: I'm confused, I'm using the same file methods in another script and they're working fine there, it's just the sw.